# Working with data.tables within data.tables

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

In my research I often have the issue of lists within lists. Today, I run again into a program which I do not know how to best solve within R. I try to solve the issue with `data.table` but run into troubles.

I have data for various startup firms, say `Startup1`, `Startup2`, etc . For each startup I have information on investors, `VC1`, `VC2`, etc. I also have information on when a startup began its activity: `StartYr` and funding rounds characterized by the investors `VCNam`, the year a funding round takes place `FRYr`, and the amounts received `FMoney`. For each Startup the number of funding rounds changes and the number of investors also changes.

As a first exercise, I try to compute the time it takes between the `StartYr` and a given funding year. Here is my code:

```
library(data.table)
    dtF1=data.table(VCNam=c("VC1","VC2"),FRYr=c("2006","2007"),FMoney=c(10000,20000))
    dtF2=data.table(VCNam=c("VC1","VC3","VC4"),FRYr=c("2010","2011","2012"),FMoney=c(10,20,30))
    dt=data.table(FirmName=c("Startup1","Startup2"),StartYr=c("2001","2005"),FdRounds=c(dtF1,dtF2))
dt[]

FNams=unique(dt$FirmName)
for (nam in FNams){
     print(paste("dealing with firm",nam))
     dtSub=dt[FirmName==nam,.(StartYr,FdRounds)]
     StartYr=as.integer(dtSub[,StartYr])
     print(StartYr)
     print(dtSub[,FdRounds][[1]])
     print(dtSub[,FdRounds][[2]])
     FRYr=dtSub[,FdRounds][[3]]
     print(as.integer(FRYr)-StartYr)
}
```

And here is my output:

```
> dt[]
   FirmName StartYr       FdRounds
1: Startup1    2001        VC1,VC2
2: Startup2    2005      2006,2007
3: Startup1    2001    10000,20000
4: Startup2    2005    VC1,VC3,VC4
5: Startup1    2001 2010,2011,2012
6: Startup2    2005       10,20,30

and:
[1] "dealing with firm Startup1"
[1] 2001 2001 2001
[1] "VC1" "VC2"
[1] 10000 20000
[1]  9 10 11 # the right answer
[1] "dealing with firm Startup2"
[1] 2005 2005 2005
[1] "2006" "2007"
[1] "VC1" "VC3" "VC4"
[1] -1995 -1985 -1975 # a crazy answer.
```

The result 9 10 11 is correct for `Startup1` but not -1995 etc for `Startup2`. Inspection reveals that dt no longer contains the right order of elements: VC name, year of funding, money.

**Question 1:** I am open to use lists, dplyr, or data.table which is the suggested approach to this issue. The data is hundreds of firms so time is an issue.

**Question 2:** How can I solve this problem which is representative of problems I encounter all the time? Related: is there a more functional programming way of dealing with this issue?

Comment: I appreciate your well formulated question with its detailed explanation of the sample data.

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to analyse why the `for` loop returns the wrong answer because of the convoluted design of the underlying data structures. Another issue is that `FRYr` and `StartYr` are given as character but the OP wants to compute differences  of these.

Therefore, I suggest to use a "clean"  design consisting of just two `data.table`s in a SQL-like manner:

1. One for all funding rounds `FdRounds`,
2. and a second for the base data of all startup firms `Startup`

using `FirmName` as key to identify rows in both tables which belong to each other.

These can be constructed from the existing data:

```
library(data.table)
dtF1 = data.table(
  FirmName = "Startup1",
  VCNam = c("VC1", "VC2"),
  FRYr = c("2006", "2007"),
  FMoney = c(10000, 20000)
)
dtF2 = data.table(
  FirmName = "Startup2",
  VCNam = c("VC1", "VC3", "VC4"),
  FRYr = c("2010", "2011", "2012"),
  FMoney = c(10, 20, 30)
)
FdRounds <- rbindlist(list(dtF1, dtF2))
FdRounds[, FRYr := as.integer(FRYr)]
FdRounds
```

> ```
>    FirmName VCNam FRYr FMoney
> 1: Startup1   VC1 2006  10000
> 2: Startup1   VC2 2007  20000
> 3: Startup2   VC1 2010     10
> 4: Startup2   VC3 2011     20
> 5: Startup2   VC4 2012     30
> ```

```
Startups = data.table(
  FirmName = c("Startup1", "Startup2"),
  StartYr = c("2001", "2005")
)
Startups[, StartYr := as.integer(StartYr)]
```

Now, we can join both tables and do computations

```
FdRounds[Startups, on = "FirmName"][, FdYearAfterStart := FRYr - StartYr][]
```

> ```
>    FirmName VCNam FRYr FMoney StartYr FdYearAfterStart
> 1: Startup1   VC1 2006  10000    2001                5
> 2: Startup1   VC2 2007  20000    2001                6
> 3: Startup2   VC1 2010     10    2005                5
> 4: Startup2   VC3 2011     20    2005                6
> 5: Startup2   VC4 2012     30    2005                7
> ```

---

For a more compact view, the data can be aggregated by startup firm:

```
FdRounds[Startups, on = "FirmName"][, FdYearAfterStart := FRYr - StartYr][
  , lapply(.SD, toString), by = .(FirmName, StartYr)]
```

> ```
>    FirmName StartYr         VCNam             FRYr       FMoney FdYearAfterStart
> 1: Startup1    2001      VC1, VC2       2006, 2007 10000, 20000             5, 6
> 2: Startup2    2005 VC1, VC3, VC4 2010, 2011, 2012   10, 20, 30          5, 6, 7
> ```

From the joined result it is easy to compute the total funding each startup firm has received across all investors:

```
FdRounds[Startups, on = "FirmName"][
  , .(TotalFunding = sum(FMoney)), by = .(FirmName, StartYr)][]
```

> ```
>    FirmName StartYr TotalFunding
> 1: Startup1    2001        30000
> 2: Startup2    2005           60
> ```

---

This approach is also more versatile as it allows to aggregate by investor as well:

```
FdRounds[Startups, on = "FirmName"][
  , .(NumberFR = .N, TotalFunding = sum(FMoney), 
      InYears = paste(range(FRYr), collapse = "-")), by = VCNam]
```

> ```
>    VCNam NumberFR TotalFunding   InYears
> 1:   VC1        2        10010 2006-2010
> 2:   VC2        1        20000 2007-2007
> 3:   VC3        1           20 2011-2011
> 4:   VC4        1           30 2012-2012
> ```

```
FdRounds[Startups, on = "FirmName"][
  , .(NumberFR = .N, TotalFunding = sum(FMoney), 
      InvestedIn = toString(FirmName)), by = VCNam]
```

> ```
>    VCNam NumberFR TotalFunding         InvestedIn
> 1:   VC1        2        10010 Startup1, Startup2
> 2:   VC2        1        20000           Startup1
> 3:   VC3        1           20           Startup2
> 4:   VC4        1           30           Startup2
> ```

Comment: Thanks this does my job! Excellent answer. Unfortunately, I am not enough experienced yet to attribute a point.

Comment: ... and, you have also answered an issue which I had on my mind, namely the aggregation of the fundings. Very smart! Thanks!!

Comment: @MichaelRockinger I am pleased to have guessed your requirements. Even if you do not have enough reputation yet you can mark the answer as accepted at your convenience.